# netlogo, gis extension not drawing and giving an error

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to draw a few gis files using netlogo. I have 3 shape files (area boundary, building polygons & road network).
When I use the gis:draw command one of the files draws perfectly (area boundary) but with the other 2 shape files. One doesn't draw at all (road network) and  other gives the following error "unsupported shape type 15 error while observer running GIS:LOAD_DATASET"

The largest file size is 1927KB

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does the road share a spatial extent with your area boundary? For your second error- your building polygons may have some Z or M data associated with them. There is a way to remove those in ArcMap if you're using that that- [here's one option](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010389) .

Comment: Thanks for the info. I figured out the first error. The shape files were in different CRS. As for the second error its probably what you said. However I am using different shapefile with same info for now and so far its alright.

Comment: Right on, glad you sorted it out!